# Does not return the year in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

The query

```
SELECT Name AS Period,YEAR(Name) AS Year FROM periods;
```

| Period | Year |
| --- | --- |
| 202001 | NULL |
| 202002 | NULL |
| 202003 | NULL |
| 202004 | NULL |
| 202005 | NULL |
| 202006 | NULL |
| 202007 | NULL |

It works fine in MariaDB, but not in MySQL.

How can I solve that?

Comment: What is the data type for the `Name` column?

Comment: `202001` is a string and not a Date. Use a string function like LEFT().

Comment: Did you define that column differently in mysql and mariaDB?

Comment: @RiggsFolly No, they are the same.

Comment: @forpas how can i do what you suggest?

Comment: function LEFT(): https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following query

```
SELECT Name AS Period,Year(DATE_FORMAT(concat(Name,'01'), '%Y%m%d')) AS Year FROM periods;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I tried it and it doesn't work!

Comment: I think you need a full date (with a day number) in order for `STR_TO_DATE()` to actually work properly @Tejas

Comment: Updated the query, Please check now

Comment: @Tejas works perfectly, thank you very much!